# Программа не работает. Ошибка повреждения кучи. Помогите, пожалуйста, найти ошибку

Tags: c++, динамические-массивы

```
// Study56.cpp: определяет точку входа для консольного приложения.
// CppStudio Level: Normal Task 15 Переписать все элементы двумерного массива в одномерный

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "rus");
    int n, m;
    cout << "Введите количество строк матрицы: ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Введите количество столбцов матрицы: ";
    cin >> m;
    int** M = new int *[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        M[i] = new int[m];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            M[i][j] = rand() % 100;
        }
    }
    cout << "Вы ввели: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            cout << setw(3) << M[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    int *mas = new int[n*m];
    for (int i = 0; i < n ; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < n*m; k++)
            {
                mas[k] = M[i][j];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "Запись матрицы в строку: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < (n * m); i++)
    {
        cout << mas[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Когда вы обьявляете укзатель на  массив указателей   `int** M = new
   int *[n];` тем самым вы говорите, что этот указатель `M` содержит
   адрес начала массива  `n` - го количества указателей, т.е. в массиве
   есть `n` штук указателей. Поэтому это:

   for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
   {
      M[i] = new int[m];
   }

является грубой ошибкой, поскольку вы питаетесь инициализировать не  `n` штук указателей, а `m`. Замените на правильный вариант:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {
       M[i] = new int[m];
   }
```

2. Дальше вы пишете цикл, который можно назвать безобразием

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < n ; i++)
   {
       for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
       {
           for (int k = 0; k < n*m; k++)
           {
               mas[k] = M[i][j];
               break;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Здесь каждый раз вы инициализируете `mas[0]` и  прекращаете работу вложенного цикла, поэтому замените на:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n ; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
         mas[i * m + j] = M[i][j];
```

В принципе, чтобы записать матрицу в строку,  одномерный массив вовсе и не нужен, так что  ваш `int *mas`  совершенно лишный.

И, наконец,  вы выделяете память в свободной области, оператором `new`, поэтому вы должны освобождать всю эту память в конце программы:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)        
        delete [] M[i];
delete [] mas;
```